# Display text or a label based on javascript value

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first attempt at javascript and trying to display a value in a text box based on the value of another.

Here is what I have, I have updated based on answers, but still not working,

sql data looks like:

avg_price  evaluation
933.18  -99.39
1,024.50    61.48
948.00  13.87
939.92  78.56
907.89  20.84
840.73  -0.31
759.06  -16.71
718.83  -14.14
738.08  66.10

```
<body>

    <?php
    $sql = $stmt = $dbo->prepare("SELECT avg_total_price, evaluation FROM view_evm
    ");
    $stmt->execute();
    ?>
    <h1>EVM Details</h1>

    <TABLE class="data-table">
        <caption class="title">Calculations </caption>
        <thead>

        <TR>
            <TH>Avg Total Price</th>
            <TH><input type="text" name="avg_price" id="avg_total_price"  </TH>
            <TH>  </th>
       </TR>
       <tr>
           <TH>Evaluation</TH>
           <th><input type="text" name="evaluation" id="evaluation" onkeyup="updateRecommendation(event)"></th>
          <th><input type="text" name="evalresults" id="evalresults"</th>
       </tr>


    </table>
        <table id="table_results" class="data-table">
            <caption class="title"></caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <TH>Avg Total Price</TH>
                    <th>Evaluation</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <HR>
            <?php
                while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                extract($row);
            ?>
            <tbody>
                <TR>

                    <Td><?php echo $row['avg_total_price']; ?> </Td>
                    <Td><?php echo $row['evaluation']; ?> </Td>
                 </TR>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
            </tbody>
    </table>

<script>


var table = document.getElementById('table_results');

for (var i=1; i< table.rows.length; i++)
    {
        table.rows[i].onclick=function()
            {

                document.getElementById("avg_total_price").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                document.getElementById("evaluation").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;

            };
    }

function updateRecommendation(event) {
    var currenteval = event.target.value;
    if (currenteval > 0){
        document.getElementById("evalresults").value = "Sell";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("evalresults").value = "Buy";
    }         
};
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is no element whose id is `"currenteval"`. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you're missing closing tags (`>`) on your input elements.

Secondly, instead of passing the value, try passing the `event` and getting the value from that, like so:

**Working snippet**

```js
function updateRecommendation(event) {
    var currenteval = event.target.value;
    if (currenteval > 0){
        document.getElementById("evalresults").value = "Sell";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("evalresults").value = "Buy";
    }         
};
```

```html
<tr>
    <th>Evaluation</th>
    <th><input type="text" name="evaluation" id="evaluation" onkeyup="updateRecommendation(event)"></th>
    <th><input type="text" name="evalresults" id="evalresults"></th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not element with id `currentval`, but what you want to accomplish is the following:

```js
function updateRecommendation(value) {
  var currenteval = parseInt(value);
  if (currenteval > 0) {
    document.getElementById("evalresults").value = "Sell";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("evalresults").value = "Buy";
  }

};
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <TH>Evaluation</TH>
    <TH><input type="number" name="evaluation" id="evaluation" onkeyup="updateRecommendation(this.value);" </th>
      <th><input type="text" name="evalresults" id="evalresults" </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

See? the `evalresults` is being modified according to the entered value in `evaluation` input.